# RN FireBase push notification, cant access notification title & body when app is closed (getInitialNotification)

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Code below works fine except, when I close the running and click next incoming notification there is not title and body.

I share code below, the line with

```
async createNotificationListeners() {
    /*
    * Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
    * */
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
      const { title, body } = notification;
      console.log('onNotification:');

        const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
          sound: 'sampleaudio',
          show_in_foreground: true,
        })
    ...

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      console.log('onNotificationOpened:');
      Alert.alert(title, body)
    });


    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();

    if (notificationOpen) {
      debugger
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification; // title and body undefined
      const { data } = notificationOpen.notification;// and data has only google.delivered_priority ..
      console.log('getInitialNotification:');
      Alert.alert(title, body)
    }

  }
```

how can i get the notification content by opening app via clicking incoming notification,

my app package json like;

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is closed, your listener will not work in react native rather than it will only work when the app is in *foreground and background*. So for the state when app is closed you have to add a background task in your react native application.

> Now you have to use [HeadlessJS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) funtionality which is available in
>   react native.

You can refer here for Firebase Official documentation :- https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background

Hope this helps....Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is new Url for @abhikumar22 answer:

https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background